# How to fetch Json Array from an Api and return it as a collection

Tags: arrays, json, spring, api, collections

I am trying to fetch data from JSON array and return it as a collection.

```
[
    {
        "name": "Adam Road Food Centre",
        "type": "HC",
        "owner": "Government",
        "stalls": 32,
         "address": "2, Adam Road",
        "postalcode": 213446,
    }
]
```

The following is my code. Does anyone know if my method of fetching the data correct?

```
    try(InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes())){
        final JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is);
        final JsonArray result = reader.readArray();
        final JsonArray readings = result.getJsonArray(0);
        final String name = readings.getString(0, "name");
        final String address = readings.getString(0,"address");
        final String postalCode = readings.getString(0,"postalCode");

        return readings.stream()
            .map(v -> (JsonObject)v)
            .map(Hawker::create)
            .map(w -> {
                w.setName(name);
                w.setAddress(address);
                w.setPostalCode(postalCode);
                return w;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, typically we make class that correspond our body called DTO
for example:
this:
[ { "name": "Adam Road Food Centre", "type": "HC", "owner": "Government", "stalls": 32, "address": "2, Adam Road", "postalcode": 213446, }]
would be represented:

```
class MyDTO{
  private String name;
  private String type;
  private String owner;
  private int stalls;
  private int address;
  private int postalcode;
  // getters
  // setters
}
```

and in your controller class api method should be something like this:

```
    public ResponseEntity<Void> myEndPoint(@RequestBody List<MyDTO> myDto) {
      // use myDto
}
```

Comment: @zed123  
If you are looking to make a rest call  please look at:
for feign:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html
for retrofit:
https://square.github.io/retrofit/